# Assets in Vue app not loading when published to Github pages

Tags: vue.js

I'm publishing my SPA that I'm making with Vue and Buefy to my a `gh-pages` branch a of private repo, just so I can test if everything will load normally.

Later, I'll upload the finished website to the actual public repo, which is tied to my custom URL (I'm redesigning the website from scratch, using a diff tech).

Since Vue websites needs to be built for distribution, I'm using an NPM package to do this for me: https://github.com/KieferSivitz/vue-gh-pages

```
"deploy": "node ./node_modules/vue-gh-pages/index.js --branch gh-pages -m \"Deploy to gh-pages.\""
```

When deploying the website, it loads only partially. The images won't load, and the router will not work (links to other pages won't work).

I'm storing images in the `assets` folder, and using `require('@/assets/logo.png')` to load them (at least it works with localhost).

The images are trying to be loaded from `https://<username>.github.io/img/logo.d2151712.png`.

I read that I would need to set the `publicPath` to my project name, since currently the website is being served from `https://<userName>.github.io/<projectName>/`, but with that, the whole website is 404-ing.

With that property, the whole website would try to load from `https://<username>.github.io/<projectName>/<projectName>`.

I think that somewhere, there's a setting adding `<projectName>` to router, but not adding elsewhere.

#### Edit

I tried to force `vue-router` to get the correct base, without setting the `publicPath`:

```
base: "<projectName>/", //process.env.BASE_URL,
```

But the routes are stil not working, since I'm lazy loading them using `import("@/views/Page.vue")`.

Comment: What did you try as a value for publicpath? Should be '/<projectName>/' I think.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too. Here's more info https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5460

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that I would need to set the `publicPath` to my project name, since currently the website is being served from https://.github.io//, but with that, the whole website is 404-ing.

Indeed, the `publicPath` property is required to be set to the GitHub repo name, surrounded by slashes (i.e., `/github_repo_name/`). The 404's are caused by `vue-gh-pages` [removing the leading slash from URLs in `index.html`](https://github.com/KieferSivitz/vue-gh-pages/blob/8fa4174/index.js#L80):

```html
<!-- <script src=/github-pages-vue-demo/js/chunk-vendors.c4b075fb.js></script> --> <!-- before -->
<!-- <script src=/github-pages-vue-demo/js/app.9b45ea45.js></script> --> <!-- before -->
<script src=github-pages-vue-demo/js/chunk-vendors.c4b075fb.js></script>
<script src=github-pages-vue-demo/js/app.9b45ea45.js></script>
```

> With that property, the whole website would try to load from `https://<username>.github.io/<projectName>/<projectName>`.

That's a side effect of the slash-removal, making the URLs relative. [Relative URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Creating_hyperlinks#Absolute_versus_relative_URLs) are relative to the current location (appended to the current directory). For example, with this GitHub pages URL - `https://tony19-sandbox.github.io/github-pages-vue-demo/`, a relative URL of `github-pages-vue-demo/js/app.9b45ea45.js` would resolve to:

```
https://tony19-sandbox.github.io/github-pages-vue-demo/github-pages-vue-demo/js/app.9b45ea45.js
```

And an absolute URL of `/github-pages-vue-demo/js/app.9b45ea45.js` would resolve to:

```
https://tony19-sandbox.github.io/github-pages-vue-demo/js/app.9b45ea45.js
```

> I think that somewhere, there's a setting adding `<projectName>` to router, but not adding elsewhere.

`vue-router` has a [`base`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) property for that purpose, but Vue CLI (`@vue/cli-plugin-router`) correctly [defaults it to `process.env.BASE_URL`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/84abd11/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-router/generator/template/src/router/index.js#L40). That environment variable is already equal to `publicPath` from your Vue CLI config, so there's no need to set it.

#### Workaround

If you wish to continue using `vue-gh-pages`, you could use [`patch-package`](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) to [disable the slash-removal](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/github-pages-vue-demo/blob/3b2a93d/patches/vue-gh-pages%2B1.19.0.patch) ([`index.js` line 109](https://github.com/KieferSivitz/vue-gh-pages/blob/8fa4174/index.js#L109)) as shown below:

```js
//editForProduction();
if (repository !== null) {
    pushToGhPages();
}
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/github-pages-vue-demo)

Otherwise, I would skip that library entirely, and use [`gh-pages`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) directly in a deploy script.

Comment: It worked! Thanks. In the end I'm using a GitHub action to publish to the gh-pages with a backing script.

Comment: My website was 404'ing when navigating by 'hand', typing the address to other page. Then I saw that you added a 404 page with some script tied to the `created()` event. Why was that necessary? Isn't the router already aware of the routes?

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. It's related to the `history` mode. With that redirect, browse-typing into an inexistent page would push the user to the homepage, without refreshing the URL. So I added a catch-all route to a `NotFound` page.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that your issue is, that you want to run your Vue app in a subfolder of a domain (domain.com/subfolder/index.html). This needs to be configured in Vue CLI. Add a new file to the root of your repository, called `vue.config.js` and add the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/subfolder/' : '/',
};
```

This will set the webpack `publicPath` to `/subfolder/` when running the build process in production mode. If you are using Vue CLI < 3.3, you need to use `baseUrl` instead. You need to make sure, that your path starts with a slash.

See also [the documentation of `publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath).

---

Vue CLI has also a special section for the deployment to GitHub pages. You might also want to take a look at this: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages

Comment: That's the problem. If I set the `publicPath` property to my project name, it will try to load the page from `domain.com/projectName/projectName`. See my comment in my post.

Comment: It was an issue with the plugin that was publishing the website to the `gh-pages`. Thanks.

Comment: if posible edit to './'  , so it could be generic
module.exports = { publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './':'/' };

Comment: In "vite.config.ts" you would add `base: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/test/' : '/',`

Answer (score -1):

Vue has a configuration for that.  If you use vue client then add vue.config.js the next lines por public path property

> module.exports = {
>       publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './':'/' };

Comment: Please see my answer from the May 17th for the same solution.